# Is There a way to get a List of all the Enterprise Fields a user on Project Server has In Use?

Tags: vsto, ms-project, ms-project-server-2013, ms-project-server-2010, ms-project-server-2016

I'm building a MS Project VSTO tool (written in C#) that in many instances needs to either read or write data from a field in MS Project. Since I don't always know what field will contain the data I need, I many times need to allow the user the option to select the field they want. Getting all the basic fields is easy, my issue arises if a user is in a Project Server environment and using Enterprise fields. So my question is 2 fold:

1. Is there a way to check if the user is in a Project Server environment?
2. Is there a way to easily get all of the custom enterprise fields that are being used in MS Project? I'd like to be able to capture these fields in a collection like a list or array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to check if the user is in a Project Server
> environment?

Look at the collection of [Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.profile) to see if there is a project server one and check its [ConnectionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.profile.connectionstate) to see if it's connected to a project server.

> Is there a way to easily get all of the custom enterprise fields that
> are being used in MS Project? I'd like to be able to capture these
> fields in a collection like a list or array.

If you have access to the project server, take a look at this page, [Accessing Project Online enterprise custom fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/project/accessing-project-online-enterprise-custom-fields). Without access to the server I suggest:

- Loop through all tables and their fields to find enterprise ones.
- Allow the user to enter the name of enterprise fields and store that information for future use so that it's a one-time 'setup' for the user.